# Creating XML file from legay application

Tags: c#, xml

I have an old application that I wrote in Access VBA, the time has come to upgrade the code and the company decided to go with C# since we use it the most. My question is following, I have this code in VBA that works great,

```
Set RS2 = Db.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM TTable WHERE ID="&Forms![test]![SifraFirme]&")
su = RS2.RecordCount
RS2.MoveFirst
Do While Not RS2.EOF
//lines of code
RS3.MoveNext
Loop
RS3.Close
```

Now my question is, is there a C# command similar to Do While Not RS.EOF, any literature or examples would be highly appreciated. Just a nudge in the right direction because it has become frustrating. The main point of code above is to go through the table and filter the data and write it to XML (predefined structure) based on ID once he is done with first, move on to the second, and ...

Thank you,

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: That is one of the reasons we are "upgrading" this application to remove old insecure solutions. And this is the last problem that I can't figure out.

Comment: What is you database?

Comment: Now it is SQL, it used to be Access

Comment: Make a start on the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples see how you get on. Please come back if you have any *specific* problem to be answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to:

> The main point of code above is to go through the table and filter the
> data and write it to XML

You can read database table to some `DataSet`, using `OleDbDataAdapter` from `System.Data` namespace. Then easily work with filled `DataSet` or instantly get its XML representation by `GetXml` method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Note about set Prefer 32-bit app version of your C# app to use Jet.OLEDB provider
    var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=YourDBPath";
    var query = "Select * FROM TTable";

    // Introducing our DataSet
    var dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();

    using (var connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        var command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, connection);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
 
            using (var dataAdapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(command))
            {
                // Fill DataSet
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
            }

            // Get XML representation of DataSet and save to XML file
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"TTable.xml", dataSet.GetXml());

            // Or if need to filter data before save - read through DataSet
            var TTable = dataSet.Tables["TTable"];
            foreach (var row in TTable.Rows.Cast<System.Data.DataRow>().ToArray()) // using System.Linq needed
            {
                    
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle exception in some way
            System.Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }  
    }
      
    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thank you all. You guys rock

Answer (score 0):

C# has the [XMLWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter?view=net-6.0) class and you can use the SQL classes for querying and reading the information.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop in C# would be something like this:

```
while (!RS2.EOF)
{
    //lines of code
    RS2.MoveNext();
}
```

The ! is the [Logical negation operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-negation-operator-).

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET has the DataSet class which works with data in a way that is similar to a RecordSet in VBA.

[See Microsoft's documentation on DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset?view=net-6.0)